# Ошибка ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR при попытке сделать запрос с front на backend(Angular + .NET)

Tags: .net, angular, ssl, https

Сразу обращу внимание, что код черновой и не важно что в теле запроса, логика его обработки и т.д.
Главное сейчас получить круг:
Запрос -> сервер(backend)
Клиент(SPA) <- ответ на запрос(любой)

На стороне клиента(Angular) есть функции:

```
 cut() {
    this.cutRequest().subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
      //var result: layout = JSON.parse(value);
    })
  }

cutRequest(): Observable<any> {
   var requestData: any[] = [this.countIn, this.countOut, 
   this.standartPipe] 
   var jsonData = JSON.stringify(requestData)
   console.log(jsonData);
   return this.httpClient.post('https://localhost:5103/Cut/Cut', jsonData)
  }
```

На стороне сервера есть контроллер(фактически почти тот что из шаблона) с одним методом:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CutController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<CutController> _logger;

        public CutController(ILogger<CutController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Cut()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("557");
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Соответственно запрос на адрес `'https://localhost:5103/Cut/Cut'` маршрутизируется на метод Cut в контроллере Cut.

Все происходит на одной машине. Само SPA открывается нормально с порта 44471 и использует HTTPs.

Суть проблемы: при вызове функции `cut()` в отладчике браузера вываливается ошибка `POST https://localhost:5103/Cut/Cut net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. При этом, что естественно, метод контроллера на сервере не вызывается.

Интересно вот еще что. Так как проблема очевидно в протоколе шифрования SSL, попробовал отправить запрос по http. Как результат контроллер отрабатывает и присылает ответ, но возникает ошибка CORS хотя в при старте устанавливается политика CORS(вырезка):

```
builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
```

Но это пока побочное замечание, просто интересно почему. Как вывод из этого, маршрутизация до нужного метода отрабатывает нормально.

Что же можно с этим сделать? Старался выжать самое нужное, если нужна еще какая-то информация пишите в коментах. Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся)!

Comment: А на вашем сервере SSL настроен?

Comment: @Alexey Ten, да наверное стоило пояснить. Все делается на localhost, по сути это шаблон из VS с использованием Angular. Больше сказать не могу в силу того что большего не знаю. Само SPA открывается через https нормально. backend висит на порту 5103, а Angular: "SPA proxy is ready. Redirecting to https://localhost:44471."